# Monit daemon interval setting...global or service-level?

Tags: monitoring, monit

I'm configuring monit on Ubuntu 11.04. In `monitrc`, the following setting controls the interval at which the monit daemon monitors services...

`set daemon 120`

Is this a global setting? If I want to check different services, such as permissions on a directory and an http service, how can I configure monit to check directory permissions every week while pinging the http service every 5 minutes?

I understand it's possible to use the `-d interval` option when executing monit, but according to the documentation, this checks services only once, then exits, without repeating; not helpful for my needs since I need it to continuously execute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the per-test interval in cycles.

See [this similar ServerFault.com question](https://serverfault.com/questions/286315/monit-connection-test-frequency/290149#290149) for some more information.

ie: if your interval is 300 seconds you could run an http check every cycle while running the weekly check every 2016 cycles.

Comment: I get it...one interval is one cycle, so for each test I may specify a different cycle from 1 to n, whatever the requirement to run that test based on multiples of the interval time, makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately there's an upper limit to number of cycles you can set in config file -- `sizeof(long long) * 8)`